# POST forms: How to put GET parameters in action attribute?

Tags: html, forms, post, get

I have this form:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="draft.html?test=1">
            <button type="submit">Valid</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But when I click on valid it doesn't redirect to draft.html?test=1 but to draft.html. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:** I know that I should favour `<input type="hidden">` but I want to use it for a POST form.

**EDIT 2:** This is a stupid question, as soon as I change the method of the form to POST, the problem is resolved.

Comment: Make a hidden input text tag and give it an attribute name="test" and value="1" and also in form set method to get.

Comment: Yes but in fact I want to use it for a POST form.

Comment: in POST you should avoid displaying the data.

Comment: Yes but that is not sensible data, just the name of the page to be included by the index.php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you absolutely need to put it on action attribute** you can use `method="POST"`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="draft.html?test=1" method="POST">
            <button type="submit">Valid</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Otherwise if you want to send your data trough `GET` use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="draft.html" method="GET">
            <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
            <button type="submit">Valid</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a form with `method="GET"` (the default), the query string of the action is replaced with the data in the form.

Don't put the data in the action attribute. Put it in hidden input elements instead.

```
<form action=draft.html>
    <input type=hidden name=test value=1>
    <button>Valid</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes but in fact I want to use it for a POST form.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi — So just use a POST form instead of asking questions about a GET form then.

Comment: Yes, I fixed my first post.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi — With your edit to your question, the problem you describe doesn't occur.

Comment: Indeed, I'll change it again.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```html
<form action="draft.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="test" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Valid</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You don't need to hack the input element with CSS when you have the native type=hidden.